# How to plot numpy array versus row number

Tags: python, arrays, plot

Assume we have a csv file with a single column. I can plot it with ;

```
data = np.loadtxt(file)
test = data[:,0]
plot(test)
```

and it plots test versus the row number (entries). But I want to multiply this row number so that I can plot ;

```
plot(test,row[i]*25)
```

I think there should exist a simple way than to arrayize the row number. Any pythonic way to handle this issue ?

Comment: Have a look at `numpy.arange`. E.g. `y = 25 * np.arange(test.size)`. `numpy.indices`, `numpy.mgrid`, `numpy.ogrid`, `numpy.ndindex`, and `numpy.ndenumerate` are similar functions that are also useful to be aware of.

Answer (score 4):

given a data you can do :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=[0,2,113,....,19,5]
x_coordinate = [ 25 * i for i in range(len(data)) ]
plt.plot(x_coordinate,data)
plt.show()
```

you'll have all x label indexes as multiples of 25

or use the numpy array functionality:

```
x_coordinates = 25 * np.arange(test.size)
```

Comment: This is OK but it's not vectorised.

Comment: If by vectorized you mean using numpy array functionnality, I have edited the answer using the numpy array function `x_coordinates = 25 * np.arange(test.size)` like Joe Kington suggested you in the comments.